# How to check whether video gets finished playing or not?

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to check whether a video gets all finished playing or not. Means we want a state where video gets all finished playing means it reached to the end of the video.

Give me any suggestion related to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implement `OnCompletionListener` in your activity like this:

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener{
```

when you will implement this, eclipse will add a new method "`onCompletion`" in your class:

```
@Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //video playback has ended, now do whatever you want to do.
    }
```

after this set the onCompletionListener for your videoview like this:

```
mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(VideoDisplayView.this);
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: What if I'm using a 'view'? Its class is "com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView." I tried your method, but it seems like it only works for VideoView.